# Why "PEP 572 -- Assignment Expressions" is not enabled by default?

Tags: python, syntax

Is there any technical reason not to enable assignment expressions as default behavior of the language? I mean for assignment operations to always return their value, like:

```
a = (b = 1)
```

Please note I am not looking for opinions. I am looking for technical reasons (backward incompatibilities for instance) that prevent such implementation. This seems like genuinly useful feature, like `if` in Scala.

Comment: your code does not represent an assignment expression in the sense of the PEP... `a = b = 1` works fine already...

Comment: Assignment *isn't* an expression at all; it's a statement. This was a deliberate choice to prevent `if b = 1:` from parsing at all, so that you can't write that instead of `if b == 1:` by mistake.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, with parentheses it does not.

Comment: @Marcin i know (that is the reason i left them out...). but you are right, that is not really an answer to your question (hence just a comment).

Comment: In Py 3.8 `a = (b := 1)` works just fine, so it appears to be "enabled" by default — so your premise is wrong.